# Image exists, not null, but I get an NullPointerException on it

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmapfactory

**Short introduction**

The app I am working on at the moment, takes an image from a JSON, if correct it uses it and saves it as a loading image on next use.

**Problem**

All of the sudden, the app started crashing on loading and on further inspection, the `file.isFile && file.canRead()` check I had in place returns positive but it still crashes on `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`.
The byte count of the file is 8k, compared to other devices I've used, where that same image actually has 43k bytes.

The image json is part of a much larger json message (approx 500kb) and it's not at the start or the end. The last use before this happened there was no problem loading or sign showing that download might have stopped half way. Even so, the image still has 8kb so I imagine it should just create something with the part it has rather then throwing NullPointerException

I am using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 4 and code is in Kotlin. I must have run it on this device 100 times, and even after this occurred it runs perfectly fine on other test devices, plus the iOS app that gets the exact same json at start up

**What I am looking for**

Advice on how to deal with the issue, or information whether it's a known bug in Android or Kotlin. I can probably reinstall the app on the device and it will be ok again but would not want this happening once the app was released, if I can prevent it.

**LaterEdit**: With Xaviers suggestion, I have copied the file onto the desktop and it's definitely malformed, when it loads it actually shows some seriously malformed image of things running on the Mac. I have tried to upload it but it just displays as an empty white image. It still has 8kb, so it contains some data. **How is this possible and can it be prevented?**

**Code**

Loading up the app, I check if image exists and load it into an imageView

```
try {
     if (DesignSupport().imageExists("logo", this)) {
         if (DesignSupport().loadImage("logo", this) != null) {
             imageView.setImageBitmap(DesignSupport().loadImage("logo", this))
         }
     }
 } catch (error: Error) {
     Log.i(tag, error.stackTrace.toString())
 }
```

Check if image exists

```
fun imageExists(string: String, context: Context) : Boolean {
        val path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + context.applicationInfo.name + "/" + string + ".png"
        val file = File(path)
        return (file.isFile && file.canRead())
    }
```

Load up the image

```
    fun loadImage(string: String, context: Context) : Bitmap {
            val path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + context.applicationInfo.name + "/" + string + ".png"
            val fis = FileInputStream(path)
// it crashes at the next line, but when I print fis.available() it returns 8200
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis)
        }
```

**Crash Log**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.GeneralAccessScreens.startupScreen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis) must not be null
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis) must not be null
at SupportMethods.DesignSupport.loadImage(DesignSupport.kt:45)
at .GeneralAccessScreens.startupScreen.onCreate(startupScreen.kt:34)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
```

**Import statements**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.util.Base64
import android.util.Log
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the crash is in the same `loadImage()` method and not on another one? In the error log it says that the crash is in `BitmapFactory.decodeReso…ystem(), R.drawable.logo)`, which seems a different one.

Also, have you tried to do a Rebuild first? I've seen many problems in AS 3.0 betas that are resolved by doing that.

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream)), even if `fis` is null it should not crash with this error, just return a `null` (emphasis is mine).

> Decode an input stream into a bitmap. **If the input stream is null, or cannot be used to decode a bitmap, the function returns null.** The stream's position will be where ever it was after the encoded data was read.

Just to discard things, can you add the `import` statement for `BitmapFactory`? Should be `import android.graphics.BitmapFactory`.

Comment: Thank you, I just realised that log was from a previous crash whilst trying different solutions, so not the clean one, I have updated the crash log

Comment: @AlexIoja-Yang I'm still seeing the same crash log.

Comment: And the rebuilding doesn't do anything, I have tried to run it on a different device and it doesn't have any issues, then reconnect this one and same thing still. I imagine at some point it must have corrupted the data but it should still load a weird looking image

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis) must not be null this is the difference on the top line, instead of the BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(), R.drawable.logo). That was as an alternative if size was less then x kb, but then I realised I shouldn't just try to avoid the problem by setting an arbitrary limit.

Comment: Updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: but fis is not null, fis.available() returns 8200, which I assume must be a character count. Also I have added the import statement but it's a class of a few methods, so not all is relevant to these 2 methods shown here.

Comment: @AlexIoja-Yang I think that what you say looks like the more plausible explanation. This, or some kind of file corruption. I tried to step into the method, but is native, so no luck there. I would try to download the file to your computer and check there.

Comment: I have printed a fit.read().toString() and it shows 137. I am not familiar with android, I hoped that would be the content of the file.

Comment: `fit.read()` will read first first byte of the file, and `.toString()` convert it to a printable string. 137 is the first byte of a PNG file header: http://libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html So, at least the beginning of the file probably is correct. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The specific exception is thrown because `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis)` returns `null` while the function is specified to return a non-nullable object. Either make the return value nullable or define an appropriate replacement if it does return `null`.

In the background Kotlin generates the following "java" code:

```
Bitmap tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(tmp, "BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis)");
return tmp;
```

The source of the exception is the `Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull` call.

Comment: But that's the problem, it is not null and it passes any check I made on whether it would be null. The crash happens while decoding, although the stream is not null.

Comment: The crash happens after decoding, that specific exception is generated when checking the return value of a function, in this case `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`.