# Prevent swipe to delete recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe, swipe-gesture

I want to catch a vertical swipe in an horizontal `RecyclerView`. Each item is simply a `CircleImageView`.
I found many resources on internet (like [Drag and swipe with RecyclerView](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf), [Android - Swipe to delete RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985719/android-swipe-to-delete-recyclerview)) but those solutions ends deleting the item. I don't know if the term *swipe* requires also that the item is deleted or not.
What I want to achieve is **to catch the swipe action on an item in the RecyclerView**, but **without delete the item itself** from the `RecyclerView`.

I think that a good idea is to override the method `onChildDraw()` like suggested here: [How to detect if Recyclerview item is being swiped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617569/how-to-detect-if-recyclerview-item-is-being-swiped), but I can't understand how to achieve the behaviour I want.
My idea is: while the user swipes an item, the item itself moves in that direction; when the user end the touch event, the item has to come back to the original position (maybe changing the background color).

EDIT 1:
[How to have swipe to delete and swipe to archive in two colours in Recyclerview Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000316/how-to-have-swipe-to-delete-and-swipe-to-archive-in-two-colours-in-recyclerview) probably can help, but it doesn't achieve the behaviour that I need. The item has to **come back to the original position**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have swipe to delete and swipe to archive in two colours in Recyclerview Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000316/how-to-have-swipe-to-delete-and-swipe-to-archive-in-two-colours-in-recyclerview)

Comment: I had explained it correctly in the above question. please try it

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I want. I don't want something like Gmail, I want that the item comes back in the starting position. If it's possible with your solution can you explain me how to do it? I don't understand the meaning of the different function's calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `RecyclerView` has `RecyclerView.Adapter` attached to it. The adapter determines what information that the `RecyclerView` can see and display. So, if item number 10, out of a 100-item backing array (managed by you) is swiped, the adapter can report that the array now contains 99 items and not ever present the swiped item to the `RecyclerView`. That way the item appears to be deleted but is maintained internally and still accessible programmatically. How you manage that internal state is up to you and dependent upon your implementation.

---

If, however you want to not remove the item from the screen but just change its appearance, I think that you would need to look at the method `onItemDismiss` that actually removes the item and notifies the adapter of the data change.

```
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
    mItems.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

It is here that you would make the change. The item would stay in the adapter. You would also need to flag that position as "swiped" in case the view holders are recycle so you can maintain the visual "swiped" state.

```
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
    // Change background color, etc.
}
```

Take a look at code that has a "swipe to delete" function with "undo" for some ideas. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41740993/6287910) is an example with a dialog that is called before deletion actually occurs if "Cancel" is clicked. There are many other examples of "undo" available. What you are trying to do can be considered to be an immediate and implicit "undo" with a visual change to the background.

If you want to have the item move back into position after a swipe, the following should work:

```
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I saw that the adapter contains the item in the `onSwped()` method. Only after the method returns the item disappears? What I think I should do is in the `onSwped()` method add again the item in the adapter in the previous position and notify the insertion, but the element is already in the adapter.. I think I can't understand something of this process!

Comment: @A.Wolf I updated the answer with a way to flag an item as "swiped" assuming you are using the method [here](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf).

Comment: Thank you! It's cleaner than what I implemented. I will try it as soon as possible.